Why is `kube-prometheus-stack` complaining about secret "prometheus-kube-prometheus-admission" not found
Given ArgoCD v2.13.2 and kube-prometheus-stack Helm Chart v67.3.1 (and likely other versions of both), ArgoCD may fail to install the chart with the kube-prometheus-stack-operator pod citing that the secret "kube-prometheus-stack-admission" is not found. How can I fix this permanently in a GitOps compatible way?

Per the comments found here https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/values.yaml#L2367, updating your Helm values to include the following block should resolve this issue:
      prometheusOperator:
        admissionWebhooks:
          annotations:
            argocd.argoproj.io/hook: PreSync
            argocd.argoproj.io/hook-delete-policy: HookSucceeded
          mutatingWebhookConfiguration:
            annotations:
              argocd.argoproj.io/hook: PreSync
          validatingWebhookConfiguration:
            annotations:
              argocd.argoproj.io/hook: PreSync
          patch:
            annotations:
              argocd.argoproj.io/hook: PreSync
              argocd.argoproj.io/hook-delete-policy: HookSucceeded

